# Nivo slider not showing images on the first page load but loading on refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

Hello my nivo slider isn't loading images on the initial page request and hangs up on the ajax loading symbol, but after a page refresh the images load perfectly.

The images are all highly compressed so that shouldn't be an issue.

The site is a uni project located here http://microlab.clickgarden.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add nivoSlider to "**success**".

```
    function loadPage(url)
    {
    url=url.replace('#page','');

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load_page.php",
    data: 'page='+url,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){
        $('#slider').nivoSlider(); // add this line
        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
        {
            $('#pageContent').html(msg);
            $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
        }
    }

    });

    }
```

Comment: In addition to this dont use multiple ids. Check it out [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/id)

Comment: tip: dont forget to [validate your markup](http://validator.w3.org/) its a useful stuff